# How to fix 'ELF error: Dynamic stack frames detected but not enabled' while running the Solana helloworld example C program using SBF v2 processor?

Tags: solana-program, solana-test-validator, sdk

using `solana sdk 1.14.11` [1], my goal is to execute the Solana helloworld example C program [2] using the SBF v2 processor [3] on the local `solana-test-validator`.

When deploying the program locally, it fails with:

```
Transaction executed in slot 6120:
  Signature: <sig>
  Status: Error processing Instruction 1: invalid account data for instruction
  Log Messages:
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
    ELF error: Dynamic stack frames detected but not enabled
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 failed: invalid account data for instruction
```

I wonder if the issue **`ELF error: Dynamic stack frames detected but not enabled`** is due to the fact that `config.dynamic_stack_frames=true` is missing somewhere[4].

Any idea where this parameter should be set ?

Or on the other causes of this issue ? [5]

Thanks

[1] Solana SDK v1.14.11

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/tag/v1.14.11

[2] Solana Helloworld example

https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld

[3] SDK `bpf.mk` file for C programs

<solana-sdk-1.14.11>/bin/sdk/bpf/c/bpf.mk

`BPF_C_FLAGS := ... -target bpf-solana-solana -mcpu=sbfv2 ...`

same issue when the dynamic-frames feature is explicitly enabled

`BPF_C_FLAGS := ... -target bpf-solana-solana -mcpu=sbfv2 -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +dynamic-frames`

[4] References to `config.dynamic_stack_frames=true`

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/23481

https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/pull/274

[5] input ELF is correctly flagged as `EF_SBF_V2` (`0x20`)

```
$ readelf -h <...>/solana-example-helloworld/dist/program/helloworld.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Linux BPF
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x2d8
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          3096 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although dynamic stack frames are supported on the VM, as you've noticed, they're not enabled in the Solana validator.

To enable it on the validator's VM, you'll need to change this line to `true` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3234af41a7a94f56123591c02f0ec6fdde100337/programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs#L177

and then build your own test validator by running `./cargo build --bin solana-test-validator` from the root of the repo.