# How to fix "ELF error: Relative jump out of bounds at instruction" on example-helloworld deploy (target sbf-solana-solana cpu sbfv2)?

Tags: solana-test-validator, solana-sdk, sdk

We are using the latest Solana monorepo [1] and our goal is to run the Solana example-helloworld [2] Using sbf-solana-solana target and sbfv2 CPU.

First, we patched `programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs` line `177` to set `dynamic_stack_frames` to `true` [3]

Second, we updated the `sbf.mk` script `SBF_C_FLAGS` variable and added `-mcpu=sbfv2 -D SOL_SBFV2=1`. Overall the build line is like `clang -Werror -O2 -fno-builtin -std=c17 -target sbf -mcpu=sbfv2 -D SOL_SBFV2=1 -fPIC -o ../../dist/program/helloworld/helloworld.o -c ./src/helloworld/helloworld.c` (`-isystem` parameters skipped for readability)

As a side note, `-D SOL_SBFV2=1` seems important to be added, may be related to static system calls, as we found occurrences of the `SOL_SBFV2` macro in the sdk files, as for example in `sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/log.h` [4]

When we deploy the helloworld program we get the following error:

```
$ solana program deploy solana-example-helloworld/dist/program/helloworld.so
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Relative jump out of bounds at instruction #34
```

Unfortunately, the dump does not show instruction `#36` [5]

However if ever we omit the `-D SOL_SBFV2=1` parameter of the build command, we can deploy the program successfully, but when we run the program we get the following error:

```
$ npm start
...
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (GitHub/solana-example-helloworld/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4153:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (solana-example-helloworld/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4115:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (solana-example-helloworld/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4103:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (solana-example-helloworld/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:30:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program xxx invoke [1]',
    'Program xxx consumed 5 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: unsupported instruction at instruction 90',
    'Program xxx failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]
}
```

instruction `#90` is visible in the dump [6]

How to solve the `ELF error: Relative jump out of bounds at instruction #34`?
Should we add additional patch to `programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs` ? (tried without success)
Should we activate some other features for the sbf target ? [7] (tried without success)

Thanks

[1]

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana

solana-cli 1.15.0 (src:`00000000`; feat:`1157313049`, client:SolanaLabs)

commit `6e4ecc67587f8ff277a54b08d6ec229080354df7`

[2]

https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld

[3]

file `programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs`

```
   174          external_internal_function_hash_collision: feature_set
   175              .is_active(&error_on_syscall_bpf_function_hash_collisions::id()),
   176          reject_callx_r10: feature_set.is_active(&reject_callx_r10::id()),
   177          dynamic_stack_frames: true,
   178          enable_sdiv: false,
   179          optimize_rodata: false,
   180          static_syscalls: false,
   181          enable_elf_vaddr: false,
   182          reject_rodata_stack_overlap: false,
   183          new_elf_parser: false,
   184          aligned_memory_mapping: true,
   185          // Warning, do not use `Config::default()` so that configuration here is explicit.
   186      };
```

Solved thanks to [How to fix 'ELF error: Dynamic stack frames detected but not enabled' while running the Solana helloworld example C program using SBF v2 processor?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/how-to-fix-elf-error-dynamic-stack-frames-detected-but-not-enabled-while-runn)

[4]

file `sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/log.h`

```
18  #ifndef SOL_SBFV2
19  void sol_log_(const char *, uint64_t);
20  #else
21  typedef void(*sol_log__pointer_type)(const char *, uint64_t);
22  static void sol_log_(const char * arg1, uint64_t arg2) {
23    sol_log__pointer_type sol_log__pointer = (sol_log__pointer_type) 544561597;
24    sol_log__pointer(arg1, arg2);
25  }
26  #endif
```

[5]

command `V=1 make -C ./src/program-c dump_helloworld` to investigate instruction `#34` when the program is built with `-target sbf -mcpu=sbfv2 -D SOL_SBFV2=1`

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000120 <helloworld>:
      36:   79 12 08 00 00 00 00 00 ldxdw r2, [r1 + 8]
```

[6]

command `V=1 make -C ./src/program-c dump_helloworld` to investigate about instruction `#90`, when program is built with `-target sbf -mcpu=sbfv2`

```
0000000000000290 <LBB0_10>:
      82:   79 11 18 00 00 00 00 00 ldxdw r1, [r1 + 24]
      83:   61 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 ldxw r2, [r1 + 0]
      84:   07 02 00 00 01 00 00 00 add64 r2, 1
      85:   63 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 stxw [r1 + 0], r2
      86:   18 01 00 00 05 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 lddw r1, 1541
      88:   b7 02 00 00 06 00 00 00 mov64 r2, 6
      89:   85 10 00 00 ff ff ff ff call -1
      90:   b7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 mov64 r0, 0
      91:   05 00 ec ff 00 00 00 00 ja -20 <LBB0_11>
```

[7]

command `$ llc --march=sbf --mcpu=help`

```
  alu32           - Enable ALU32 instructions.
  dummy           - unused feature.
  dwarfris        - Disable MCAsmInfo DwarfUsesRelocationsAcrossSections.
  dynamic-frames  - Enable dynamic frames.
  reloc-abs64     - Fix 64bit data relocations.
  sdiv            - Enable native SBF_SDIV support.
  solana          - Enable Solana extensions.
  static-syscalls - Marker feature used for conditional compilation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been able to fix the issue by activating static syscalls and using the latest solana-labs/rbpf git version (may be related to https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/pull/434 recently committed)

1. Activate static syscalls in the bpf loader. Edit `programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs` line `180` and set `static_syscalls` to `true`
2. Use the git version of solana rbpf [1] instead of the version used in the solana monorepo. For your cloned version of rbpf to be used by your solana environment. In the solana monorepo, edit all `Cargo.toml` files that refer to `solana_rbpf`

   a. `find . -name Cargo.toml -exec grep -l solana_rbpf {} \; | xargs`

   b. comment the line `solana_rbpf = "=0.2.38"`

   c. add the line `solana_rbpf = { path = "<your-path>/GitHub/solana-labs/rbpf", version = "=0.2.38"}` to replace the commented line
3. Rebuild the solana test validator with the command `./cargo build --bin solana-test-validator`
4. Rebuild the solana cli with the command `cd cli; cargo build`

[1] https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/